#  Failure to install a package from the command line?

Tags: command-line

Here's an example:

```
HP-G62-Notebook-PC:~$ ccsm
The program 'ccsm' is currently not installed.  You can install it by typing:
sudo apt-get install compizconfig-settings-manager
reborn@reborn-HP-G62-Notebook-PC:~$ sudo apt-get install compizconfig-setting-manger
[sudo] password for reborn: 
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package compizconfig-setting-manger
HP-G62-Notebook-PC:~$
```

Comment: why it is unable to E:? sudo apt-get install compizconfig-settings-manager
reborn@reborn-HP-G62-Notebook-PC:~$ sudo apt-get install compizonfig-settings-manger
[sudo] password for reborn: 
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package compizonfig-settings-manger
reborn@reborn-HP-G62-Notebook-PC:~$

Answer (score 6):

`compizconfig-setting-manager` isn't quite the same string as `compizconfig-settings-manager`.  Cut and paste might be your friend for that kind of thing.

Answer (score 0):

yes. As  geekosaur said it is nothing but a typo error. the package name is '`compizconfig-settings-manager`' not  '`compizconfig-setting-manger`'. you missed the letter '`a`' in the word '`manager`' and `s` in `settings`.

Comment: Actually there's two typos. So one down, one to go. ;)

Comment: @nem75: lol. i haven't noticed the 's' in settings. Thanks..